# java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null , Cannot invoke "String.substring(int)" because "this.proxoolAlias" is null

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

[image: Project directory structure]

I am self learning and working on a basic hibernate program which has Player class and here I am trying to connect it to mysql database.

Player.java:

```
package com.to;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity

@Table
public class Player {
    
    @Id
    private int playerId;
    private String playerName; 
    private int age;
    private String teamName;
    
    public Player(int playerId, String playerName, int age, String teamName) {
        super();
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.age = age;
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [playerId=" + playerId + ", playerName=" + playerName + ", age=" + age + ", teamName=" + teamName
                + "]";
    } 
    
    public Player() {
        
    }   

}
```

HibernateMain.java:

```
package com.control;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.to.Player;

public class HibernateMain {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(com.to.Player.class);
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = 
                    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Player p1 = new Player(10,"Amit",30,"India");
        session.save(p1);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 ~ Hibernate Search, full-text search for your domain model
 ~
 ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later
 ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simplilearn_db</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hr</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am encountering the below listed...

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.proxool.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider.getConnection(ProxoolConnectionProvider.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at com.hibernatedemo.control.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:21)

Apr 02, 2023 1:02:36 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists Player
Apr 02, 2023 1:02:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
Apr 02, 2023 1:02:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: The url cannot be null
Apr 02, 2023 1:02:37 PM org.hibernate.proxool.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider stop
WARN: HHH030006: Exception occurred when closing the Proxool pool
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.substring(int)" because "this.proxoolAlias" is null
    at org.hibernate.proxool.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider.stop(ProxoolConnectionProvider.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.deRegisterChild(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at com.hibernatedemo.control.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:21)

Apr 02, 2023 1:02:37 PM org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl stopService
INFO: HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.proxool.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider]
org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH030006: Exception occurred when closing the Proxool pool
    at org.hibernate.proxool.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider.stop(ProxoolConnectionProvider.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.deRegisterChild(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at com.hibernatedemo.control.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.substring(int)" because "this.proxoolAlias" is null
    at org.hibernate.proxool.internal.ProxoolConnectionProvider.stop(ProxoolConnectionProvider.java:233)
    ... 11 more

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at com.hibernatedemo.control.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:21)
```

I've also checked the username and password for database, It is all correct...

I tried checking with hibernate version issues and also added javaassist 3.20.0 jar but didn't work either.

EDIT: It seems like the ProxoolConnectionProvider.java file is missing and I think that is the reason to this issue...Is there any option to add it to the project...?

Answer (score 0):

try to add the word "hibernate" at the start of property desc.

sample.

```
<property name = "hibernate.dialect">
         org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
         com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
         jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
      </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
         root
      </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
         root123
      </property>
```

Comment: I tried but didn't seem working...